# Which ancient Greeks are known to have commentated on Zeno's Paradoxes?

Tags: ancient-philosophy, greeks, history, zeno-of-elea

The Stanford Encycl. of Philosophy mentions that we know of Zeno's work only through various secondary sources, "principally through Aristotle and his commentators."

I was wondering, which other ancient Greek commentators on Zeno are known? I would be especially interested to know which (if any) great ancient Greek mathematicians are known to have commentated on Zeno.

Answer (score 4):

The prime critic was Aristotle : 'Physics', VI.

Plato does not set out Zeno's arguments but in his dialogue, 'Parmenides', there is in connexion with the paradoxes some argument or interplay between the Platonic Socrates and Zeno on the issue of whether there is a plurality of things or only the Parmenidean One : 'Parmenides', 127d-128e.

It depends, of course, on what one counts as 'ancient' but there is also critical material in Simplicius of Cilicia (c.490-560 CE) and Philoponus of Alexandria (c. 490-470 CE).

REFERENCES

N. Booth, ' 'Zeno's Paradoxes', The Journal of Hellenic Studies, Vol. 77, Part 2 (1957), pp. 187-201.

Florian Cajori, 'The History of Zeno's Arguments on Motion: Phases in the Development of the Theory of Limits', The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 22, No. 1 (Jan., 1915), pp. 1-6.